# How do I return only one value from Table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to return the final value from the Table.For example something like Table[n-1] value.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[f[n], {n, 1, 10}][[-1]]
(* f[10] *)
```

But one might wonder why you wouldn't just type `f[10]`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary dimension "table"

```
last[list_List] :=
 Nest[Last, list, Length[Dimensions[list]]]
```

For a vector

```
list = Array[x, 5]

(* {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]} *)

last[list]

(* x[5] *)
```

For an [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
list = Array[x, {3, 3}]

(* {{x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[1, 3]}, {x[2, 1], x[2, 2], x[2, 3]}, {x[3, 1], x[3, 2], 
  x[3, 3]}} *)

last[list]

(* x[3, 3] *)
```

For a higher dimensional `Array`

```
list = Array[x, {5, 10, 100}];

last[list]

(* x[5, 10, 100] *)
```